# show/hide buttons on resizable navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nivagation bar with button links in row on resize the window to smaller width each button wrap underneath which changing the navigation height, gets removed from the nav and appended into a dropdown menu.
[image: navbar]

I managed to append wrapped buttons when the navigation height is higher than 80, but it will only work if the initial size of the screen is big which will have all buttons in one row. but if the screen started at a smaller width it won't append all wrapped buttons in the menu.

[image: height>80]

**Here is my attempt**

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var navbar = $("#navbar");
  var list = $("#list");
  var btns = $("#btns");
  var last_element;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.children().length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (list.height() > 80) {
        last_element = list.children().last();
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#btns .dropdown-menu").prepend(last_element);
        }, 300);
        last_element.remove();
      }
    }, 500);

  }
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  /*    display: inline-block; */
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap style -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="navbar">
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
    <li class="item">item 5</li>
    <li class="item">item 6</li>
    <li class="item">item 7</li>

  </ul>
  <div id="btns">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
         </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I would love to have similar action to this image,

[image: gif]

**Can someone offer a snippet suggestion or what should I use to implement such action?**

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated - move hidden items to dropdown menu**

---

First, make changes on css:

1. apply `display: flex` to `#navbar`.
2. calculate the maximum height of `#list` manually and set `max-height` & `overflow: hidden` property to it. In this case, the maximum height of `#list` would be **73px** but not 80px. (the height of `.item` **65px** + top margin of `.item` **4px** + bottom margin of `.item` **4px** = **73px**) If the max-height is not correct, `#list` may not hide the `.item`s properly.
3. set `display: inline-block` for `.items`.

`

```
#navbar{
   width: fit-content;
   background-color: #dbdbdb;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 10px;

   /*Flex layout*/
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   align-items:center;
}

#list{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;

   /*Calculate the max-height and set overflow hidden*/
   overflow:hidden;
   max-height:73px;
}

.item{
   color: #333;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 30px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
   margin: 4px 2px;
   list-style-type: none;

   /*Move text-align center to here*/
   text-align: center;

   /*Remove flex layout & add display inline-block*/
   display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-menu{
   width: 200px;
   padding: 0 20px;
}
```

`

Then, update the $(window).resize() function.
The below code will check if the item is being moved to a hidden area. Moreover, use `.html()` to refresh the dropdown menu.

```
let list = $("#list");
let listItems = $("#list .item");
let dropdownMenu = $("#btns .dropdown-menu");

$(window).resize(function() {
    let listPosition = list.position().top;
    let hiddenItems = listItems.filter(function(){
    return $(this).position().top - listPosition > 0;
  }).clone();
    dropdownMenu.html(hiddenItems);
});
```

Comment: This help in hiding and showing buttons but didn't append them on the menu when they are hidden and removing them from menu when visible

Comment: You can remove the `$(window).resize() ` function from your javascript code. I guess that may work.

Comment: Actually I need `window.resize` to have the full functionality I need for the menu. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I should apologise! I have a read to your question again and I found that I ignored the part "move hidden item to dropdown menu". And so I updated my answer. Please look if the updated version helps :D

Comment: YES! this is what I need. Thank you, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using bootstrap. You still can do this without any JS if a collapsible menu on mobile devices is what you need.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You too are ignoring the requirement of creating a menu for elements when hidden. this definitly requires JS!

Comment: This is totaly different from what I need. Thank you for your attempt to help.